# How to add bullets in crystal reports dynamically when using XML data

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using SAP crystal report tool for generating reports. I have a requirement to add bullets for a dynamic list. I searched in web but I could not find a way when there is xml data ([A link when it is used parameters](http://skillforge.com/crystal-reports-add-true-bullets-to-a-list-in-a-text-object-with-the-chrw-function/)).
Can someone assist me to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this .
Create new formula fields > insert bullet as string ("* ") > Join XML Field (drag and drop XML Field)> Run (it will show if there any errors) > Save and Close.
[image]